# simple mod_rewrite keeps causing 404

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, uri

I'm desperate... this test rule here works just fine so the server is certainly configured properly. It refreshes the page as expected.

```
RewriteRule /hello.htm /index.htm [R]
```

But I'm trying to simply refresh the page from `example.com/123` to `example.com/index.htm?id=123`. I thought I could do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$ /index.htm?id=$1 [R]
```

But it just won't work. Get 404 all the time, checked my logs, nothing useful in there.

I'm HORRIBLE at this and hope to get some help.

Comment: Is the rule in a .htaccess or somewhere else?  [This](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) points out the regular expressions match differently depending on where the directive occurs.

Comment: it's inside the .htaccess

Comment: Are you sure your first rule worked from within your .htaccess?

Comment: If it's in the .htaccess you must omit the leading slash, i.e. `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /index.htm?id=$1 [R]`. why your first rule works is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally figured out my problem, and given the number of questions re: 404 issues I imagine it's relatively common.

My server is shared, i.e. I have hosting with one of the usual larger companies that use virtual servers, etc...

As a result, I needed to **add the full domain name** to my redirect. so instead of doing `/index.htm?id=$1` I had to do `http://www.example.com/index.htm?id=$1`

And presto, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try should work for you

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /index.html?id=$1 [NC,R=301]
```

Comment: all you did is change the flag at the end, right? It's not the cause of the 404.